# Minimum Size of Qt app if only user interface is made in Qt

Tags: macos, qt

I am writing a MacOs X based app, the back-end is all written in C/C++ (non-Qt). I need to implement a user interface for the app. Since I am better in C++ I think Qt is the best choice for me.

The application in itself is not huge, it is a small windows based application supporting fairly simple functionality.

what I am doubtful about is that, footprint of the app would be huge if I use Qt , is that true? do you think it can be managed under 5MB if I use Qt - I am only going to use the user-interace of the Qt library all IO and other operations are in standard C++. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you [link your application to the Qt statically](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/deployment-mac.html#static-linking) I think it could fit, depending on the features you are using. You can check [this Qt Project forum post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8594) for more information:

> In my case, the static QtCore lib is about 14MB, QtGui lib is 36 MB, while a simple static-linked GUI program consumes only 5MB.

However, I don't think the size of the application really matter these days on desktop systems, and if you are able to save a lot of your time/money, few MBs bigger bundle should not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

At least on Windows with Vs2010 and static linking under 5MB is certainly possible.

I had an application that used QMainWindow and many of its features, and about 8 modal dialogs using QDialog.

With static linking and the use of UPX the total size was 4.2 MB. Without a binary compressor it might be hard to hit this target. Just make sure link time code generation is enabled so unreferenced parts of the Qt lib can be removed by the build tool chain. And watch the license agreement on static linking too.

Also see this question:

[Minimal Qt executable-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450455/minimal-qt-executable-size)